# Java, инициализация внешнего массива в методе

Tags: java, массивы, методы, передача-параметров

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] list = null;

        init(list, 5); // инициализация массива длиной 5

        System.out.println("list: " + Arrays.toString(list)); // list: null
    }

    public static void init(int[] list, int length) {
        list = new int[length];
    }
}
```

Почему в вышеуказанном примере не получается инициализировать переменная `list` в методе `init` и как это обойти? Где можно почитать об этом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, `int[]` - ссылочный тип. Но вы передаете в функцию ссылку - она копируется (сам адрес внутри, а хранящая его переменная - совершенно другая), а в теле метода пытаетесь изменить адрес **копии**.

Посему, чтобы добиться именно того, чего вы желаете, необходимо **повысить косвенность** (например, воспользовавшись массивом из одного элемента, содержащий ссылку на `int[]`):

```
public class Main {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] listRef = new int[1][];

        init(listRef, 5); // инициализация массива длиной 5

        int[] list = listRef[0];

        System.out.println("list: " + Arrays.toString(list));    
    }    

    public static void init(int[][] listRef, int length) {
        listRef[0] = new int[length];
    }
}
```

Но это можно рассматривать из академического интереса, выглядит это коряво и создает лишнюю нагрузку на GC.

Почитать в том числе об этом можно в [первом томе](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/25151213/) двухтомника К. Хорстманна.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что это - параметр, передаваемый в метод. Эта переменная уже инициализирована. В вашем коде она содержит `null`. Обойти это никак нельзя, да и непонятно, что в данном случае означает "обойти".

Почитать об этом можно в каждом учебнике. Глава про методы, функции, их параметры и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] list = init(5); // инициализация массива длиной 5

    System.out.println("list: " + Arrays.toString(list)); // list: not null
}

public static int[] init(int length) {
    return new int[length];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно, чтобы метод `init` возвращал созданный массив:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] list = null;

    list = init(5); // инициализация массива длиной 5

    System.out.println("list: " + Arrays.toString(list)); // list: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}

public static int[] init(int length) {
    return new int[length];
}
```